# What are the best practices to display hardcoded pre-made long texts in an xcode project?

Tags: swift, string, xcode

This will soon be my first time publishing an iOS app, and I just finished writing my privacy policy and terms & conditions texts. Best idea I came up with was to display them in UITextViews in dedicated view controllers.

But both texts are very long. And they already have headers, titles, bullets points... they're all set up and ready to be used !

Obviously, copying the text from
[this beautiful .txt format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4Mco.png) and hard-pasting it inside a String property is impossible because it makes the text completely plain again (and of course... I also need to get rid of every « " » and replace line breaks already implemented inside the text with \n, because [it otherwise conflicts with a String declaration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QL2P9.png)).

It's going to be very time consuming, and I'll end up with a very poor visual result anyway.

Is there a simpler and better way to display a text file in its original format ? Maybe by importing it ?

I hope my question was clear and understandable enough !

Thank you very much in advance for your help, I really appreciate :)

Comment: You can use `static let privacyPolicyBodyText = """ longText with new lines """, seee https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47234762/swift-4-programming-triple-quotes But I'd suggest instead to add a `.txt` to your app as a resource file, and read the text from it. For rendering, you could use Markdown (and use new available decoding in recent iOS version or a third party lib), or HTML that is available since a long time in `NSAtttrtibutedString`.

Comment: Hi Larme ! Thank you very much for all these advices :) I didn't know the triple quotes, that's great ! But I might as well add the .txt as a resource file, like you said. Concerning Markdown, I've never used that either. I asked Google about it, but it seems like Markdown is specific to SwiftUI, or am I mistaking ? Also, I'm not sure how to use NSAttributedString's HTML option but I'll investigate, you already gave me a lot of hints and keywords to broaden my searches throughout the internet ;) Thanks again for helping a newbie !

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/3796598-init